# Python autobahn WAMP Messaging Protocol

Tags: python, protocols, specifications, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I`m pipeing WAMP protocol through Pythons multiprocessing.pipe,
and I nead to reimplement WampCraClientProtocol.

Question A: In the ambiguous case of:

```
exclude  = ['ABCDEFGH001', 'ABCDEFGH002', 'ABCDEFGH003']
eligible = ['ABCDEFGH001', 'ABCDEFGH002', 'ABCDEFGH003']
[TYPE_ID_PUBLISH, topicURI, event, exclude, eligible]

# Is the exclude or eligible stronger?
# (Can I do following?)

exclude  = set('ABCDEFGH001', 'ABCDEFGH002', 'ABCDEFGH003')
eligible = set('ABCDEFGH001', 'ABCDEFGH002', 'ABCDEFGH003')
eligible -= exclude
[TYPE_ID_PUBLISH, topicURI, event, [], list(eligible)]
```

Question B: can `excludeMe` all ways be replaced with `[self.session_id]`?

```
[TYPE_ID_PUBLISH, topicURI, event, excludeMe] ==
[TYPE_ID_PUBLISH, topicURI, event, [self.session_id]]
```

/Aki R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question A: the case is not ambiguous - the message wont be received by anyone. The logic is: (Subscribers AND Eligible) \ Exclude.

Question B: Both messages will result in the same behavior of the broker.